# Функция требует минимальной версии android 8

Tags: java, android

Собственно говоря вот проблема мне нужна функциональность вот этой функции:

```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

.ofPattern и .withZone но Android Studio пишет что требуется минимально 8 версию андроида:

```
Call requires API level 26 (current min is 21): java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter#ofPattern
```

Не ну я могу поставить проверку, но мне этот функционал нужен и для версий ниже 8. Что мне делать подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: ну используйте SimpleDataFormat тогда например

Comment: В принципе да надо попробовать. Ну в коде было использован DateTimeFormatted вот я за него и уцепился. Но вообщем да надо попробовать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) и будут у вас фичи (не все) из java 8+ даже на sdk 21